# A simpler way to use document.ready with require js

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am using require js and jquery for my current project. And  I am wondering what would be the best way to make use of document.ready with require.js.

my current file structure :

main.js

```
define(["Jquery"], function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SomeButton").click(function () {});
});
```

test.js

```
define(["main"], function () {
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#AnotherButton").click(function () {
});
});
```

test1.js

```
define(["main"], function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#AnotherButton").click(function () {
});
});
```

As you can see, I am using document.ready in each of the three files. Is it better way to write the code that makes use of document.ready without defining this event in each module file. I want to keep these module as it is, but just want to make sure that dom is ready before the codes gets executed.

one thing i can do is in main.js document.ready event load all the modules file. but as i have different pages that uses different js files, combining all of them together is not an option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite enough. You can trigger document.ready from multiple places, but all of them would be asynchronously called. So if you want them to be triggered in a sequence, then you should think about arranging them at one place, otherwise it should be fine.